# Why Robert & Virginia plan theft at final seconds of the new 2000 millennium countdown?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In *Entrapment (1999)*, Robert & Virginia planned a bigger heist in Kuala Lumpur: $8 billion from the "International Clearance Bank" in the North Tower of the Petronas Towers. But they choose theft in the final seconds of the new 2000 millennium countdown. Why so?

Comment: Because Y2K.  If you aren't familiar with Y2K, google it.

Comment: I know Y2K created huge bug, bug is not enough to steal the money.

Comment: and also **Y2K** doesn't make any problem for CCTV Camera installed over the world.

Comment: There *were*, in fact, concerns that the Y2K bug would shut down everything.  Of course, we Technology people learned it wasn't really that big of a deal, and most applications of any importance were adjusted anyway long before Y2K hit, but still the general population feared and believed there was going to be a huge problem.  The movie simply capitalized on that fear to make a "believable" reason as to why the heist was planned for that moment and the possibility that it might be successful.

Comment: Friend of mine made half a million quid that year, "fixing" y2k bugs for major banks... the fear was strong, the pay was high, the movie, however, was a struggle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But they choose theft in the final seconds of the new 2000 millennium countdown. Why so?

Because that was their window of opportunity to access the mainframe.

Virginia explained....

> Now, because of the [**Millennium Bug**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem), our friends at International Clearance will be running **integrity tests**....[snip].just before midnight, local time, they'll shut down the mainframe in each zone for 30 seconds.
>
> Now we need those **30 seconds to patch into the mainframe**. We then need 10 seconds of one-on-one time with the computer to download the "stuff".

Since the Millennium is the next night...that's when they have to do it.